# Add a link to the user's profile from the moderator message thread

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, moderator-tools, moderator-messages

When a user is privately messaged by a moderator, the message typically links to the user's profile, but since it's a part of the message body the link is sometimes edited out.

It'd be handy to have a link to the user somewhere else on the page to make it easier to identify that user without digging through the site's message history.

Specifically, let's make "This user" in the screenshot below link to the user's profile:

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even better IMO would be to have the user name and avatar appear atop the page.

---

This has been implemented. Each message now has a header like this one:

[image]

Comment: Hello @Anna, I am writing in reference to your Arqade account: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/1925/anna-lear. We've received many flags on your posts citing awesomeness. There's a relevant page from the [help center](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) that reads: "We’re excited to have you here." This is only a comment, but please take it under advisement.  Looking through your history I can see that you obviously have a lot of knowledge to share, we just need you to keep doing that. Regards, badp, Arqade moderator

Comment: @badp Well played, old sport. :)